# ¿Como importar una variable generada en un bucle While a otro programa?

Tags: python, variables, while

Tengo un programa que me genera un resultado ( un numero). Este resultado cambia cada X segundos ya que esta en un bucle while. Quiero usar este resultado como variable  en otro programa. El problema viene cuando importo esta variable a otro fichero, pues me corre exactamente el mismo programa.

¿alguien sabe como importar solo la variable sin que se corra el bucle entero?

**Ejemplo**

```
Fichero "Genero un dato -> X"

def Numero_aleatorio(a, b):
    x = random.randint(a, b)
    return x


while True:
    try:

        Numero_aleatorio(1, 10)
        time.sleep(10)


    except Exception as e:

        print(e)





Fichero "Consumo el dato -> X * 2"



def Doble_Numero_aleatorio(c):
    return c * 2

while True:
    try:
        Doble_Numero_aleatorio(x)
        time.sleep(2)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: En lugar de importar la variable, importa una función que te retorne su valor actual. La variable debería ser global dentro de "Prueba" para que la función de extracción funcione. Ojo, que si tienes un "sleep", nada más ejecuta mientras estas durmiendo.

Comment: Si tienes dos procesos corriendo (uno que genera valores, otro que lo consume), lo lógico es usar "async" o bien "threads".

Comment: Buenas! gracias por contestar. Efectivamente quiero un programa que genere un dato(este lo tengo) y  por otro lado varios programas que consuman ese dato. Este dato se va actualizando cada x segundos. ¿'threads' seria lo mejor?

Comment: a mencionar que todos los programas son infinitos(while True)

Comment: Si editas la pregunta para incluir un ejemplo concreto, sintacticamente correcto, que ilustre el problema, podría intentar una respuesta. Tal como está, hay varias interpretaciones para lo que pides.

Comment: buenas! he cambiado el codigo de la pregunta. Mira si ahora te parece que tenga sentido y entiendes lo que quiero lograr. Gracias!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que planteas es un típico patrón productor-consumidor.

Necesitas ejecutar varias cosas de forma concurrente: por un lado la función que va generando los valores, por otro lado las funciones que lo vayan consumiendo. El problema es que si llamas a la función que genera los valores, ya que esa no regresa nunca (pues tiene un bucle infinito), no puedes llamar después a las otras que lo consuman (que además también tienen bucles infinitos).

Necesitas utilizar hilos o procesos separados para ejecutar esas funciones (aunque también se podría hacer una implementación asíncrona con asyncio). Para compartir los datos no basta con tener una variable compartida, es más complejo que eso, pues quieres que los consumidores la lean sólo cuando el productor la cambie, por tanto necesitas sincronizarlo todo correctamente. Típicamente para esto se usa una cola sincronizada, que es un tipo de cola con una operación `.get()` tal que si no hay datos en la cola deja al proceso esperando hasta que los haya, y otra operación `.put()` para meter datos en la cola.

Por otro lado, la función que va produciendo valores de x no necesita conocer cuántas funciones habrá que lo consuman. La cantidad de esas funciones es desconocida a priori y podría incluso variar a lo largo de la ejecución del programa.

Creo que un patrón relativamente sencillo para implementar esto podría ser el siguiente:

- Usas una cola sincronizada que Python te proporciona en `queue.Queue`
- Lanzas el productor en su propio hilo, y cada valor de `x` que vaya generando lo mete en esa cola
- Creamos una clase "controlador" que ejecutará uno de sus métodos en otro hilo separado. En ese método hay un bucle infinito en el que:

  - Espera a que aparezca un dato en la cola (el que puso el productor)
  - Ejecuta a las diferentes funciones consumidoras pasándoles ese dato como parámetro
  - Repite el bucle (aunque podemos hacer que se salga del mismo si por la cola recibe un cierto valor especial. Eso nos permitiría pararlo)

Para que eso sea genérico, la clase "controlador" mantendrá una lista interna de qué funciones son las consumidoras, y proporcionará métodos para añadir y quitar funciones a esa lista (registrar y desregistrar consumidores).

Una clase así podría ser ésta:

```py
from threading import Thread

class CoordinadorConsumidores:
  def __init__(self, cola):
    self.cola = cola          # La cola para sincronizarse con el productor
    self.consumidores = []    # La lista de funciones "consumidoras"

  # Funciones para registrar y desregistrar consumidores
  def register(self, consumidor):
    self.consumidores.append(consumidor)

  def unregister(self, consumidor):
    if consumidor in self.consumidores:
      self.consumidores.remove.consumidor()

  # Función que arranca al Coordinador en otro hilo
  def start(self):
    print("Controlador arrancado")
    th = Thread(target=self.bucle)
    th.start()

  # Bucle de procesar los mensajes que lleguen por la cola
  def bucle(self):
    while True:   # Bucle "infinito" del que se sale si _stop es True
      x = self.cola.get()   # Esperar mensaje del productor
      if x == "FIN":        # Valor especial para terminar
          break
      # Invocar a cada función consumidora registrada
      for consumidor in self.consumidores:
        consumidor(x)
    # Si salimos se termina el hilo
    print("Controlador detenido")
```

El productor por su parte sería similar, sólo que envía datos a la cola en vez de sacarlos. Y para poder pararle podemos hacer uso de un booleano en el objeto (que se puede manipular desde otro hilo):

```py
from threading import Thread
import random
import time

class Productor:
    def __init__(self, cola):
        self.cola = cola
        self._stop = True   # Este booleano permitirá salir del bucle "infinito"

    def start(self):
        print("Productor arrancado")
        self._stop = False
        th = Thread(target=self.bucle)
        th.start()
    
    def bucle(self):
        while True:
            # Generar un valor de x y enviarlo a la cola
            x = Numero_aleatorio(1, 10)
            print(f"Productor mete {x} en la cola")
            self.cola.put(x)

            # Esperar un tiempo y ver si hay que salir del bucle
            time.sleep(5)
            if self._stop:
                break
        # Al salir del bucle, el hilo terminará
        print("Productor detenido")

    # Esta función permite parar el hilo anterior
    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True
```

Ahora, programemos algunas funciones "consumidoras":

```
# Algunas funciones de ejemplo
def Doble(c):
    return c * 2

def Cuadrado(c):
    return c**2

# Algunos consumidores de ejemplo
def Consumidor0(x):
    print("Consumidor0:", x)

def Consumidor1(x):
    print("Consumidor1:", Doble(x))

def Consumidor2(x):
    print("Consumidor2:", Cuadrado(x))
```

El programa principal que pondría todo en marcha podría ser así:

```py
from queue import Queue

def main():
    # Crear la cola de sincronización e instanciar las clases Productor y Coordinador
    # pasándoles esa cola
    cola = Queue()
    productor = Productor(cola)
    coordinador = CoordinadorConsumidores(cola)

    # Registrar tres consumidores
    for f in (Consumidor0, Consumidor1, Consumidor2):
        coordinador.register(f)

    # Arrancar el coordinador y el productor y dejarles funcionar durante 20 segundos
    coordinador.start()
    productor.start()
    time.sleep(20)

    # Indicar al productor que se detenga (lo hará cuando finalice su sleep)
    productor.stop()

    # Indicar al coordinador que se detenga
    cola.put("FIN") 
    print("Todo terminado")
```

Al ejecutar `main()` sale por pantalla lo siguiente:

```html
Controlador arrancado
Productor arrancado
Productor mete 8 en la cola
Consumidor0: 8
Consumidor1: 16
Consumidor2: 64
Productor mete 7 en la cola
Consumidor0: 7
Consumidor1: 14
Consumidor2: 49
Productor mete 9 en la cola
Consumidor0: 9
Consumidor1: 18
Consumidor2: 81
Productor mete 4 en la cola
Consumidor0: 4
Consumidor1: 8
Consumidor2: 16
Productor mete 4 en la cola
Consumidor0: 4
Consumidor1: 8
Consumidor2: 16
Todo terminado
Controlador detenido
Productor detenido
```

Comment: GENIO. Mil gracias!